# Android NDK: Trying to define local module 'payload' in jni/payload/Android.mk

Tags: c, android-ndk

OK so i'm trying to build this project: https://github.com/flysands/injector using NDK, but i get this error:

No, its not my NDK, i've tried to build other projects and it worked before.

```
Android NDK: Trying to define local module 'payload' in jni/payload/Android.mk.
Android NDK: But this module was already defined by jni/payload/Android.mk.
```

Any help is appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/flysands/injector/blob/master/jni/Android.mk is wrong. `subdirs` is never initialized. `ndk-build` evaluates each `Android.mk` once per ABI, so when it evaluates the file for the second ABI it adds the subdirectories to `subdirs` a second time and causes the duplicate inclusion.

```
subdirs := $(LOCAL_PATH)/payload/Android.mk $(LOCAL_PATH)/inject/Android.mk
```

Comment: I don't have any knowledge in C or Makefile. So can you give me a guide on how to initialize it?